# "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" when assigning string to np.empty

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have the following code in a script using the `numpy` package:

```
self.map_obj_arch_id = np.empty([2])
self.map_obj_arch_id[0] = 'test'
```

But when I run it Python returns the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: test`

I understand Python can't convert `'test'` to a float, but why does Python try to convert it? What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Did you want an array of strings? By default, empty() makes an array of floats, as it says in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of strings, you need to specify so:

```
empty([2], dtype="S10") #10-character strings
```